# bound service methods are accessible in Activity, even after it is unbound and stopped

Tags: android, android-service

Consider this sequence:

```
startService > bindService > getRandomNumber > unbindService > stopService > getRandomNumber
```

According to my understanding, after I unbind a service with activity, I shouldn't have been able to access the methods in service, but I'm still able to access them after unbinding and even after stopping the service.

Any explanation for this behavior?

I have used `BIND_AUTO_CREATE` flag and the method which is still accessible is a simple random number generator method, which doesn't depend on any other object.

Here is my activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView textView;
private Intent serviceIntent;
private MyService.MyServiceBinder myServiceBinder;
ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        myServiceBinder = ((MyService.MyServiceBinder) service);
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {

    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView = findViewById(R.id.threadUpdate);
    serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
}

public void startService(View view) {
    startService(serviceIntent);

}

public void stopService(View view) {
    stopService(serviceIntent);
}

public void getRandomNumber(View view) {
    String str = "Is binder alive :" + myServiceBinder.isBinderAlive() 
            + "\n" + "ServiceConnection :" + connection + "\n"
            + "getRandomNum :" + myServiceBinder.getRandomNumber();

    textView.setText(str);
}

public void bindService(View view) {
    bindService(serviceIntent, connection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

public void unBindService(View view) {
    unbindService(connection);
}
}
```

Here is my service:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
private static final String TAG = "FromMyService";

public MyService() {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Service bound");
    return new MyServiceBinder();
}

public class MyServiceBinder extends Binder {
    public int getRandomNumber() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Service getRandomNumber");
        return MyService.this.getRandomNumber();
    }
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Service Started");
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

public int getRandomNumber() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Service getRandomNumber");
    return (int) (Math.random() * 100);
}

@Override
public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
    super.onRebind(intent);
    Log.d(TAG, "Service reBound");
}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Service unBound");
    return super.onUnbind(intent);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Service Destroyed");
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

Here is the log output:

```
    05-19 17:28:29.488 28077-28077/com.thnki.learning D/FromMyService:
    Service Started
    05-19 17:28:32.230 28077-28077/com.thnki.learning D/FromMyService: Service bound
    05-19 17:28:33.966 28077-28077/com.thnki.learning D/FromMyService: Service getRandomNumber
    Service getRandomNumber
    05-19 17:28:40.094 28077-28077/com.thnki.learning D/FromMyService: Service unBound
    05-19 17:28:42.818 28077-28077/com.thnki.learning D/FromMyService: Service Destroyed
    05-19 17:28:44.368 28077-28077/com.thnki.learning D/FromMyService: Service getRandomNumber
    Service getRandomNumber
    05-19 17:28:46.522 28077-28077/com.thnki.learning D/FromMyService: Service getRandomNumber
    Service getRandomNumber
```

Comment: the official docs say that `unbindService`: *"Disconnect from an application service. You will no longer receive calls as the service is restarted, and the service is now allowed to stop at any time."*, pay attention to `"and the service is now allowed to stop at any time."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bounded and started are two different types of `Service`.
You can create a service that is both started and bound. That is, you can start a service by calling `startService()`, which allows the service to run indefinitely, and you can also allow a client to bind to the service by calling `bindService()`.

You are doing as follows :-

```
 startService > bindService > unbindService > stopService
```

This `Service` is started Services which is bounded with an `Activity`. So when is `Unbind` system does not stop the `Service` you must explicitly stop the service by calling `stopSelf()` or `stopService()`.
**PS:-** If `Service` is serving to some SActivity the make it Bounded only no need to call `startService`, in this case `Service` will automatically destoy after last unbind.

> Note that if a stopped service still has ServiceConnection objects bound to it with the `BIND_AUTO_CREATE` set, it will not be destroyed until all of these bindings are removed. See the [Service documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service) for more details on a service's lifecycle.

**Edit:**- Well in your case Service is no longer running after unbind . You are only able to call the method cause you have reference of `Binder` that does not mean its running. Keep that in mind `Service` is an `Component` 
 To test it you can call the method below on each stage.

```
private boolean isServiceRunning(Class<?> className) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (className.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}



if(isServiceRunning(MyService.class)){
                Log.e("Service","Running");
            }else{
                Log.e("Service","NotRunning");
            }
```

[unbindService() official definition says](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#unbindService(android.content.ServiceConnection))

> Disconnect from an application service. You will no longer receive calls as the service is restarted, and the service is now allowed to stop at any time.

Comment: Hi ADM, my question was why am I allowed to access the methods in service even after the service is unbound and stopped. I have called stop service explicitly from activity but still I was able to call the method defined in the service.

Comment: If you have read the answer above . You still have `ServiceConnection` object bound to `Service` thats why Service will not get destroyed. Only use `bindService()` and `unbindService`  Do not use `startService`.

Comment: I tried that too : bindService > getRandomNumber > unBindService > getRandomNumber.  But still I am able to call getRandomNumber from activity even after unBinding

Comment: So what I understand from this conversation is that after I unbind the service, there is no guarantee that when the service object will be removed from memory, hence I have to handle it programmatically and take care that I don't call the service methods after I unbind.

Comment: @SaleemKhan didn't i tell it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50423901/bound-service-methods-are-accessible-in-activity-even-after-it-is-unbound-and-s#comment87862735_50423901)? `"and the service is now allowed to stop at any time."`

Comment: thanks @pskink, It just took some time for me to sink this in... ;)